# P tag and H2 tag in same div inline

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a p tag and h2 tag inside   a div.

the problem is when I try to align the p tag on the left side of the header , the h2 tag in the middle moves to the right

As you see the "Title" is not centered with the button.

HTML:

```
  <div class="header">
        <p class="headerp">Name</p>
        <h2 class="logo">Title</h2>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dcecf1;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.header {

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #292929;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);

}


.header h2 {
    display:inline;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header h2.logo {
    font-size: 50px;font-weight: bold;
    padding:30px 30px 30px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;

}




.headerp{

    font-family: 'Poly' Serif;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p class="headerp">Name</p>
        <h2 class="logo">Title</h2>


    </div>
    
    
    <button>Button</button>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dcecf1;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.header {

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #292929;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 23px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.67);

}

.header h2 {
    display:inline;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header h2.logo {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}




.headerp{

    font-family: 'Poly' Serif;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p class="headerp">Name</p>
        <h2 class="logo">Title</h2>
    </div>
    
    
    <button>Button</button>
</body>
```

There is one more slight "issue"

```
.headerp{

    font-family: 'Poly' Serif;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Inline-block is ignored due to the float. If 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is treated as 'block'

`.header h2.logo` was what was changed

`left: 0; right: 0;` - centers it

`position: absolute;` - The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element (from w3schools)

`padding: 0;` - There was a padding issue so removing the padding fixed it. If you want to see what the issue was, remove this line.

Comment: Alright, i removed the float , now the Name is  placed on the left from the Title, i need it to have it on the left side and the Title centered in the middle.

Comment: @therealise keep the float, remove the inline-block.

Comment: Name is on the left now but Title is not centered properly, it is moved to the right , if I give "Name"  a longer name the Title  moves more to the right

Comment: Replace your css with the css I provided. I tested it and it should work properly

Comment: i see your code works. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: just one more question. What is the reason that the Title moves to the right with my original code ?

Comment: it is because the "Name" is moving it over. If the "Name" wasn't there, it would still be centered.